# Java Logger overwrites everytime I try to put text in a log file

Tags: java, file, overwrite

```
int good = (int )(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
if(good == 1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Green result 1");
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DiceRoll.class.getName());
    FileHandler fileLog = new FileHandler("Logs.log");
    logger.addHandler(fileLog);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Green result 1");
}
```

This code is supposed to (at the bottom) put "Green result 1," into a file, but it overwrites the file every time I run the program. How would I make it put the text into the file, but not overwrite it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
FileHandler fileLog = new FileHandler("Logs.log");
```

to this

```
FileHandler fileLog = new FileHandler("Logs.log", true);
```

Remind that the second argument specifies the optional append argument. When you set to true you will write at the end of the file, without overwriting it.

Take a look at the documentation: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Answer (score 3):

You shall use [append:true](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) with the `FileHandler` as:

```
FileHandler fileLog = new FileHandler("Logs.log", true);
```

where

> `java.util.logging.FileHandler.append` specifies whether the
>   FileHandler should append onto any existing files (defaults to false).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @DarthFigo Hope that helped. Do accept it as an answer to be useful for future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FileHandler fileLog = new FileHandler("Logs.log",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [FileHandler constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler-java.lang.String-boolean-) that allows you to specify the boolean argument for append mode.